# Calling C/C++ DLL function with FAR * parameter from C#

Tags: c#, c++, c, pointers, dll

I am converting an old VB6 application into C# .Net.
The old application uses some, just as old, C/C++ DLL's which (to make it even more complex) calls another even older DLL. I would simply convert all the DLL's and get rid of them if I could but it seems I do not have all the sources needed from one of the DLL's.

So...the problem I am having is calling a function "TcpStart" from inside one of these DLL's.

I'm getting the following error:

```
PInvokeStackImbalance occurred
Managed Debugging Assistant 'PInvokeStackImbalance' has detected a problem in ...
```

This is the old C code calling TcpStart:

```
// Calling TcpStart      
     
struct Connection {
   unsigned short uSessionType;
   unsigned long  ulLastError;
   TCPService hSRV;       // session handle
   TCPTimeout secTimeout; // communications timeout
   char host[MAX_HOSTLEN+1]; // Host to connect to
   char process[50];          // Connection process name
};   

struct Connection *sConn;

uiErr = TcpStart (sConn->host, sConn->process, uSessionType, sConn->secTimeout, 20, &(sConn->hSRV));
```

From the header file, the TcpStart signature looks like this:

```
// tpapi.h

define  TCPOperation    _declspec(dllexport)

typedef LPCSTR TCPString;

typedef enum 
{
    TCPSUCCESS              = 0x0000 |  0,
    TCPSUBSYSTEM_NOT_AVAILABLE      = 0x0000 |  3,
    TCPPC_HEAP_EXHAUSTED        = 0x0000 | 22,
    //...snip...
    TCPTIMEOUT
} TCPResult;

typedef enum
{
    TCPPath,
    TCPProcess
}       TCPMethod;

typedef unsigned short
        TCPTimeout;

typedef struct TCPService_ FAR *
        TCPService;

extern TCPResult TCPOperation
TcpStart(TCPString host,            /* IN     */
     TCPString process,             /* IN     */
     TCPMethod method,              /* IN     */
     TCPTimeout timeout,            /* IN     */
     TCPTimeout fudge,              /* IN     */
     TCPService FAR * service);     /* OUT    */
```

I believe my problem stems from the last variable
TCPService FAR * service.
I believe FAR * has to do with 16-bit memory addressing? This code is from the '90s. Obviously, we are well beyond those times...

What I have so far...

```
public enum TCPMethod
{
    TCPPath,
    TCPProcess
}

// Presuming something is wrong with this.
public struct TCPService
{   
}

[DllImport("tp32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
extern public static uint TcpStart(
                                    string host,
                                    string process,
                                    TCPMethod method,
                                    ushort timeout,
                                    ushort fudge,
                                    ref TCPService service
                                    );

struct Connection
{
    public ushort uSessionType;
    public ulong ulLastError;
    public TCPService hSRV;
    public ushort secTimeout; 
    public string host;
    public string process;
};
uint uiErr;
Connection sConn;
TCPMethod uSessionType;
```

I'm getting the above error when calling TcpStart:

```
uiErr = TcpStart(sConn.host, sConn.process, uSessionType, sConn.secTimeout, 20, ref sConn.hSRV);
```

I'm presuming I have TCPService wrong but not sure what to do here and am now stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Cheers.

[Update from here]
Alright, I'm not too familiar with typedef and have read it wrong (and I was brain dead the last while).
After looking at this with fresh eyes and reading it correctly I went and found the definition of TCPService_
So...

```
struct TCPService_
{
    struct TCPService_ * next;      /* singly linked list       */
    unsigned        waiting;        /* no. of pending no-wait RPCs  */
    TCPMethod       method;     /* Pathway / Process-to-Process */
    TCPResult       lastrpc;        /* TCPResult of last RPC call   */
    TCPRetCode      retcode;        /* server/RPC return code   */
    TCPTimeout      fudge;      /* service's delay allowance    */
    CLIENT *        session;        /* session information      */
    HTASK       task;       /* task identifier      */
};
```

Where...

```
typedef unsigned TCPRetCode;
typedef unsigned TCPTimeout;
typedef int HTASK;
```

Now I have two new problems.

1. The singly linked list...
   and 2) CLIENT which I am not certain what it is but looking at source code lying around I think it's...

```
typedef struct client CLIENT;
```

From Sun Microsystems RPC or specifically rpc.h

So, not sure what to do with this.

To be clear, I am calling TcpStart which is from an implementation of RPC built to talk to a system that didn't have RPC at the time (we are talking code from the 80-90's on a non-standard mainframe).

Comment: Stack imbalance can also be the calling convention what to `TCPResult` and `TCPOperation` resolve to ?

Comment: Who allocates `service` value? Is that some handle returned by `TcpStart`? If so, you can just use `IntPtr` to pass this through in managed code.

Comment: This FAR * declaration reeks of 16bit code, but I don't think it is the issue here: it must be #defined to nothing as a 16bit DLL wouldn't load at all. As @RichardCritten suggests, I'd try to add the Cdecl convention to your interop definition. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention

Comment: How is `TCPService_` defined in the C header?

Comment: I think you also need `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = whatever_size)]` on the two nested arrays

Comment: @RichardCritten TCPResult is an enum while TCPOperation is for exporting dll. I have added this above.

Comment: @vasek Yup, it's returned by TcpStart. I'll try IntPtr but I thought those were used more for parameters passed to the calling function and not for parameters that will be returned?

Comment: @odalet oh, I had no idea, this is new. I'll try it out.

Comment: @KlausGütter typedef struct TCPService_ FAR *
        TCPService; I.e. the TCPService_ is the name of the alias

Comment: @Charlieface The two nested arrays? Do you mean the two strings in Connection? Alright, I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: What is `TCPService` defined as?

Comment: No, sorry, I meant on `Connection`, but you are not passing that anyway, so irrelevant. Actually, looking at it again, the strings are defined as `TCPString` that follows through to `LPCSTR` for which you need `UnmanagedType.LPTStr` but it might be `LPStr`. Definitely try different calling conventions, it's probably `CDecl`

Comment: @vasek I have updated (look at the bottom) with a definition for TCPService_ Seems I'm just diving into a rabbit hole...

Comment: @KlausGütter Look above. Added definition for TCPService_